# Outlook 2011 - Mark email as read

Tags: email, ms-office

In my Windows Outlook client I can change from the default behavior of marking an email as read only after hitting the space bar or opening the message to automatically marking an email as read after x number of seconds (if it is selected). Does anyone know how to set this in Outlook 2011 for Mac? I can't seem to find the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook--Preferences--Reading

You can change the time to 0 seconds